# <p:schedule> doesn't display in the presence of jquery

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to display a primefaces schedule on a xhtml page but this doesn't work.
As said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727866/primefaces-schedule-is-not-displayed-in-application), i eliminated Components which uses Ajax and i noticed that 
when i commented the link referencing the jquery file the schedual is displayed and it works fine but of course other jquery stop to work and i also got the following JS error :

```
TypeError: b3 is undefined @ http://localhost:8080/theprojectname/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces:14
```

When i uncomment the link for the jquery reference file the schedual isn't displayed and i got 2 JS errors :

```
TypeError: this.jq.mask is not a function @ http://localhost:8080/theprojectname/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces:16

and : 

TypeError: this.jqc.fullCalendar is not a function @ http://localhost:8080/theprojectname/javax.faces.resource/schedule/schedule.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces:1
```

This have happened with the PF version 4.3.1 and the 5.3.

This is my index.xhtml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/general.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css"
        type="text/css" />


    <!-- This is the jquery file reference link i've commented :  -->
    <!--     <script src="JS/jquery-1.8.3.js" /> -->

    <script src="JS/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js" />
    <script src="JS/jquery.flip.js" />
    <script src="JS/jquerygen.js" />


    <title>my app</title>

    <script>
        //<![CDATA[



        //]]>
    </script>
</h:head>

<body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form id="form1">

            <h:panelGroup id="windsarea" layout="block">
                <h:panelGroup id="gesevntsincl" layout="block">


                    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

                    <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{scheduleController.eventModel}"
                        widgetVar="myschedule">

                        <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
                            listener="#{scheduleController.onDateSelect}"
                            update="eventDetails" oncomplete="eventDialog.show()" />
                        <p:ajax event="eventSelect"
                            listener="#{scheduleController.onEventSelect}"
                            update="eventDetails" oncomplete="eventDialog.show()" />
                        <p:ajax event="eventMove"
                            listener="#{scheduleController.onEventMove}" update="messages" />
                        <p:ajax event="eventResize"
                            listener="#{scheduleController.onEventResize}" update="messages" />

                    </p:schedule>

                    <p:dialog widgetVar="eventDialog" header="Event Details"
                        showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">
                        <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">
                            <h:outputLabel for="title" value="Title:" />
                            <p:inputText id="title" value="#{scheduleController.event.title}"
                                required="true" />

                            <h:outputLabel for="from" value="From:" />
                            <p:inputMask id="from"
                                value="#{scheduleController.event.startDate}" mask="99/99/9999">
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                            </p:inputMask>

                            <h:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />
                            <p:inputMask id="to" value="#{scheduleController.event.endDate}"
                                mask="99/99/9999">
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                            </p:inputMask>

                            <h:outputLabel for="allDay" value="All Day:" />
                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="allDay"
                                value="#{scheduleController.event.allDay}" />

                            <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
                            <p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save"
                                actionListener="#{scheduleController.addEvent}"
                                oncomplete="myschedule.update();eventDialog.hide();" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:dialog>


                </h:panelGroup>

            </h:panelGroup>


            <div id="tasksbar" />
            <div id="startbutn" />

            <h:panelGroup id="startmenudiv">
                <h:panelGroup id="substartmenudiv" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <div style="visibility: hidden;">
                <BR />
                <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR />
                <BR /> <BR /> <BR />
                <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR />
                <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR />
                <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR />
                <BR /> <BR /> <BR />
                <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR />
                <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR />
                <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR /> <BR />
                <BR /> <BR /> <BR />
                <BR />

            </div>

            <div id="loginbackground" />
            <div id="logindivflip">
                <div id="logindiv">
                    <br />
                    <div class="hidden" style="font-weight: 900;">Welcome,please
                        authentificate :</div>
                    <br />

                    <div class="hidden">
                        <h:outputText value="login :" />
                        <h:inputText class="rounded" value="#{userBean.login}" />
                    </div>
                    <br /> <br />
                    <div class="hidden">
                        <h:outputText value="password :" />
                        <h:inputText class="rounded" value="#{userBean.pwd}" />
                    </div>
                    <br /> <br />
                    <div class="hidden">
                        <span class="ebbtn"> <a id="logsubmitbtn" href=""
                            title="Reset" onclick="">Submit <f:ajax event="click"
                                    execute="@this" listener="#{userBean.verifierUserDsLdap}" />
                        </a> <a id="resetbtn" href="" title="Reset" onclick="">Reset</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div id="loginphoto" />
            </div>



            <p:remoteCommand name="addNewWindow"
                actionListener="#{userBean.addNewWindow}">
                <f:param name="windowname" />
            </p:remoteCommand>

            <p:remoteCommand name="updatewinstylprops"
                actionListener="#{userBean.updatewinstylprops}">
                <f:param name="windowid" />
                <f:param name="top" />
                <f:param name="left" />
                <f:param name="width" />
                <f:param name="height" />
            </p:remoteCommand>




        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

Does someone have a clue please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not include additionals jquerys into your pages, cause its already bundled with primefcaes...

Also , use `h:outputScript` instead of `<script` and `h:outputStylesheet` instead of `link`

So your js include should look like this (notice that I first included explicitly the jquery bundled with primefaces

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript name="JS/jquery.flip.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript name="JS/jquerygen.js" target="head" />
```

place you `JS` folder under the `resources` folder in your `WebContent` folder

---

You should also read this [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)